# How does rails active model serializer handle nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Suppose that there are two tables projects and progresses, and one project has many progresses (ont-to-many):

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :progresses
end

class Progress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I does define the ProjectSerializer like below:

```
class ProjectSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :title, :state, :tags # and so on
  attribute :lateset_progress

  def lateset_progress
    object.progresses.order(created_at: :desc).first
  end
end
```

Also, I initialize my serializer in controller like this:

```
def show
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  resource = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(
               project, key_transform: :camel_lower, adapter: :json)
  render json: resource
end
```

The problem is that the nested lastest_progress does not handled by serializer and render all attributes with underscore.

The really response data is:

```
{
    "project": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "a test title",
        "tags": [
            "tag-A",
            "tag-B"
        ],
        "latestProgress": {
            "id": 45,
            "details": "run run run",
            "project_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-07-10 04:14:59 UTC",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-10 04:14:59 UTC"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh updated.

Comment: @Run What exactly you want in response? don't  you want all attributes of `progresses` ?

Comment: @Gabbar It should be camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```rb
class ProjectSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
     ...
     has_many :progresses, key: :lateset_progress do
         object.progresses.order(created_at: :desc).first
     end
     ...
end
```

If you need custom serializer class, you may use additional options for it. For example: `has_many :progresses, key: :lateset_progress, serializer: CustomProgressSerializer do  ...`

Second part about key_transform. I am not sure how work the render with `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource` instance, but I saw examples in doc where these options used for render method [rendering docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/rendering.md)

From self I'll recommend to use this notation

```rb
json_data = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(project,
    key_transform: :camel_lower, adapter: :json
).as_json
```

Through `as_json` with `fileds: [...]` option you can manage the list of attrs, it works like 'only'.
For example `as_json(fields: [:id, :updated_at])`

But need to be careful: if you use other way to create serializer object, the order of args can be different.

```rb
ProjectSerializer.new(project).as_json(nil, fields: [:id, :status])
```

All said should be truth for version 0.10.x

Comment: What a great first answer!